# Minimize UWP programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Is there a way to minimize UWP application programmatically now? My app will working on tablet in full screen mode and I don't want to drag top edge to call default minimize button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the Windows 10 update 1803 (build 17134), there is a new API that can be used to minimize your application.

```
IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();
IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();
await resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startsuspendasync

Using this API currently requires you to declare the 'appDiagnostics' capability in your manifest on insider builds. Going forward it should not be required for minimizing your own app, only for minimizing other apps.

Comment: Does it need 'appDiagnostics' capability on the release version of 1803? What about 1809+?

Comment: On 1803 you need to declare the capability. With 1809 and later you no longer need to declare the capability for minimizing your own app. You do still need the capability if you want to minimize apps other than your own though.

Comment: how to call this from C++?